# Check if Field Content is having any value or not?

Tags: mysql

I have a mediumtext field in a mysql database table. There isn't any value in it, still it is showing length of 16000.

It is either empty or NULL. Still, the `char_length` and `length` function is returning 16000.

I also tried to use TRIM function.

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(content)) FROM files_table where CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(content)) > 0;
```

While observing the actual content, there is no value in it. Not even NULL.

[image]

It can be seen in the above image, that there is no content in it. Still It is giving result of 16000.

I want to check if its actual content is having any value in it or not.

Comment: This is incorrect data insertion issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content must be something besides whitespace.  This should give you a clue:

```
select left(hex(trim(content)), 32)
from files_table
where content is not null and
CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(content)) > 0;
```

Op provided hex encoded value and it turns field was filled with 0x00 bytes:

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(replace(content, 0x00, '')))
FROM files_table
where CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(replace(content, 0x00, ''))) > 0;
```

Comment: hex is not helping

Comment: What's the result?

Comment: same result is coming. when I checked the size of hex(content) by length, it was returning length like 3200000.

Comment: The query asked for hex encoding of the string (not the length of it which is uninteresting at this point).  I added a left() so you have something short to add to your question.

Comment: left(hex(trim(content))) is giving result like 000000000000000.........

Comment: Perfect, so your field is filled with 0x00.  I added a replace to get rid of those which should now give you a 0 length unless you have something else in the field.